# Forcing smartphone to auto-zoom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive website and by no means I want any smartphone to render below 480px wide. That is, when you browse a non-responsive old website with a fixed width in your smartphone, it automatically renders the full page on screen and adjusts zoom accordingly. That's the behavior I want to enforce for devices below 480px wide (smartphones, portrait, that is).

CSS offers the following:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    @-ms-viewport {width: 480px;}
    @-o-viewport {width: 480px;}
    @-moz-viewport {width: 480px;}
    @-webkit-viewport {width: 480px;}
    @-viewport {width: 480px;}
```

Unfortunately, this is fairly new, and only latest devices understand it. For example, Windows Phone 8 gets it, but WIndows Phone 7.8 doesn't.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at the `viewport` meta tag. It has an `initial-scale` property you can use.

Comment: The problem with viewport meta-tag is that I need some sort of "conditional viewport". That is, I know the viewport meta-tag i could use, it's only I want to apply it given certain conditions (device-width < 480px).

Comment: The other problem, actually, is one reported by Quirks Mode: Device-width is not always properly reported by smartphones, so I can't trust javascript to render conditional metatags or whatever I need.

Comment: Having a look around it seems like the javascript option on Quirks Mode is the most common. If you cant rely on that for your needs maybe look for a javascript option to actually control the zoom. You can find answers to that on here. Sorry cant be more help.